# window is not defined: error with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to get my head around javascript promises as I've never used them before.
Now, I've looked at a few tutorials, and in  [this one](https://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-promises/) I decided to try the code, but when I run this:

```
if (window.Promise) { // Check if the browser supports Promises
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //asynchronous code goes here
  });
}
```

in the windows console with the command `node promise.js` I can see this error:

```
C:\Users\antobbo\Desktop\pdfSearch\promise.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { if (window.Promise) { // Check if the browser supports Promises
                                                                  ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antobbo\Desktop\pdfSearch\promise.js:1:67)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

C:\Users\antobbo\Desktop\pdfSearch>
```

Does it mean that I'm doing something wrong?
thanks

Comment: You have commented `Check if the browser supports Promises`, yet you're not running this script in a browser, which is where `window` would be defined.

Comment: There's no window in your command line...

Comment: doh! of course! sorry for the blunder...

Answer (score 0):

You are using code that expects to be in a browser because that's where `window` would be defined.

If this is node.js, then you likely already know what version of node.js you're running in since you control your own environment so you can just know ahead of time whether you're version of node has built-in promises or not.

If you are writing code for someone else to run and you might not know the version of node.js it is run in, then you probably just want a [Promise polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) that will take care of the check for you.  There are several on NPM or you can use a more full featured library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) (which is what I use and is more advanced than even native promises).

If you really want to test for the presence of `Promise` in node.js, then you do this:

```
// Check if the node.js Promises
if (typeof Promise === "function") { 
    // yes native promises are supported
}
```